# Non-negativity of $x^2y^2(x^2+y^2-3)+1$

Tags: polynomials

1. Prove that polynomial $f(x,y)=x^2y^2(x^2+y^2-3)+1$ is non-negative.
2. Prove that $f(x,y)$ cannot be represented as the sum of squares of polynomials with real coefficients.

Would be grateful to see solution.
I was thinking for couple days but unfortunately no results.

Comment: There are two questions here. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, both of them. I've edited the question.

Comment: I'm assuming that for the first question your are only considering $x,y$ that are real numbers. Otherwise you could use $f(i,i)$ as a counterexample.

Comment: To downvoter. Why this is the off-topic? I guess that this is an interesting question!

Comment: RFZ where did you get the problem...

Comment: @RFZ since you've been a member for 4 years I hope you have observed that questions that don't show your thoughts / effort are closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a famous example, due to Motzkin(1967).  Meanwhile, the continuation is that the polynomial really is the sum of squares of rational functions. Proofs of the items in the question above can also be found in lectures posted online.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function

$$
f(x,y) = x^2 y^2 (x^2 + y^2 - 3) + 1
$$

we have a stationary point at $x = y = 1$

At this point the Hessian is

$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 2 \\
 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

which is definite positive then $f(x,y)$ has a minimum at $(1,1)$ and at this point $f(1,1) = 0$ hence

$$
f(x,y) \ge 0
$$

Comment: ... and the other stationary points are at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ and along $x=0$ and $y=0$.  Moreover, it's clear that $f(x,y) \ge 0$ for $x^2 + y^2 \ge 3$, so if $f(x,y) < 0$ somewhere this must occur at a minimum.